# How to filter an object by comparing with the elements of the arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

I have an array `myarrays` and object `obj`, I need to filter the object by comparing elements of array with the key of objects.

You can view this code on StackBlitz as well: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uerzhk.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  ngOnInit() {
    const myarrays = ["createddate", "enddate"];
    const obj = {
      createddate: "30-01-02",
      progressdate: "30-01-03",
      enddate: "30-01-04"
    };
  }
}
```

The result of filtering `obj` should be the following:

```js
const filterarrayresult = {
  createddate: "30-01-02",
  enddate: "30-01-04"
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the code for desired output

```js
const myarrays = ["createddate", "enddate"];
const obj = {
  createddate: "30-01-02",
  progressdate: "30-01-03",
  enddate: "30-01-04"
};

const filteredObj = myarrays.reduce((agg, key) =>
obj[key] ? {
  ...agg,
  [key]: obj[key]
} : agg, {})

console.log(filteredObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

An array.reduce is your friend here.

```
filterarrayresult = myarrays.reduce((agg, key) => {
  if (obj[key]) {
    agg[key] = obj[key] 
  }
  return agg
}, {})
```

Comment: getting error , cannot fine name key, can you please update the stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myarrays = ["createddate", "enddate"];
const obj = {
  createddate: "30-01-02",
  progressdate: "30-01-03",
  enddate: "30-01-04"
};

let filtered = Object.assign({},
  ...myarrays.map(prev => {
    return {
      [prev]: obj[prev]
    };
  })
);
console.log(filtered);
```

This might not be an elegant solution but it's simple and works.
You can also get the same result using `reduce()` (check the snipped shared in the other answer).